# Select2 get nested options of a group in templateSelection

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have the following select2 input;

```
$('#input').select2({
    width: '100%',
    placeholder: "Brand/product name",
    allowClear: true,

    data: parseRawDataToSelect2(),

    templateSelection: formatForDisplay,
    escapeMarkup: function (m) {
        return m;
    }
});
```

And `parseRawDataToSelect2` returns following data for a select2 input:

```
[
    {
        id: '',
        text: 'group 1',
        children: [{id: 1, text: 'option 1 in group 1'}, {id: 2, text: 'option 2 in group 1'}]
    },
    {
        id: '',
        text: 'group 2',
        children: [{id: 3, text: 'option 3 in group 2'}, {id: 4, text: 'option 4 in group 2'}]
    }
]
```

I found out that `formatSelection` is no longer in use and have to use `templateSelection` instead along with 'escapeMarkup' callback. but `templateSelection` injects only the follwing data into `formatForDisplay`;

`{id: "", text: "Brand/product name"}`

I need to access the child options in a group when a selection is made however. I could not find a proper solution to get around this problem. Can somebody direct me to a correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<select></select>` element did the trick with the grouped options.
The issue was with my html element since I was using `<input></input>` to attach the select2 functionality. I am using

**Select2 4.0.3 does not work properly with grouped options with `<input>` element**. Please correct me if I am wrong.